# Will I be able to implement this design using MongoDB (via pyMongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

This will be a bit of a lengthly post, sorry in advance. I have a bit of experience using MongoDB (been awhile) and I'm so-so with python, but I have a big project and I would like some feedback before spending lots of time coding.

The project involves creating a gallery where individual presentation slides (from apple keynote '09) can be selected and parsed together into a presentation. This way a user with a few thousand slides can use this program to create a new presentation by mixing and matching old slides, rather than having to open up each presentation and copy-paste all of the desired slides into a new presentation manually.

Within the program there is a master gallery that contains all the slides. Each slide may be selected and assigned searchable tags. New "groups" of slides may be formed, where all slides with a specific set of tags are added to the group automatically. In addition, individual slides can be dragged from the master gallery and dropped into a user-created group.

There is a folder with preview images for each slide, here is why I believe I need MongoDB: By having a database where each slide is a document that contains the filename of the slide, the filename of the preview thumbnail of the slide, and an array containing searchable tag words, one will be able to query specific sets of slides very quickly. The query will return an array of matching slides which can than be looped through to add each slide thumbnail to the GUI gallery. The user-created "groups" can be individual collections, where a collection is created when a group is created, slides are added/removed from the collection as needed, and the collection can be destroyed when the group is deleted. This also will allow permanent storage as the database and its collections will persist between opening and closing the program.

My question is, will I be able to use MongoDB (through pyMongo) to do the following with decent performance:

-Create and delete collections as needed
-Copy and delete specific documents from a master collection into newly created collections
-Store an array of searchable tags in string format in a dynamic array associated with each document
-Query slides within a collection based on a single tag word stored in an array within each document
-Maintain the database between system shutdowns and opening / closing the program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post's points and questions are quoted below. My comments follow each quote.

---

> *By having a database where each slide is a document that contains the filename of the slide, the filename of the preview thumbnail of the
>   slide, and an array containing searchable tag words, one will be able
>   to query specific sets of slides very quickly.*

Sounds good. I'm assuming that the slides are in one collection.

> *The user-created "groups" can be individual collections, where a
>   collection is created when a group is created, slides are
>   added/removed from the collection as needed, and the collection can be
>   destroyed when the group is deleted.*

I suggest that you do **not** create a collection for each group. You may end up with hundreds or thousands of collections to represent "groups". This could bite you down the road if you decide you want to introduce Sharding (which may only be done on a collection). Consider creating one collection just for "groups" that will contain the unique user id to which the group is associated.

> *[Will I be able to use MongoDB, with decent performance, to] create
>   and delete collections as needed?*

Constantly creating and deleting collections is not good design. You probably do not need to do this. If you have any familiarity with RDBMS then a collection is analogous to a table. Would you keep creating dozens/hundreds/thousands of tables on the fly? Probably not.

> *[Will I be able to use MongoDB, with decent performance, to] copy and
>   delete specific documents from a master collection into newly created
>   collections?*

Yes, it is possible to take data from one collection and save it to another collection. Deleting documents is also quite easy and performant. (Indexing is your friend.)

> *[Will I be able to use MongoDB, with decent performance, to] store an
>   array of searchable tags in string format in a dynamic array
>   associated with each document?*

Yes. MongoDB is very good at this.

> *[Will I be able to use MongoDB, with decent performance, to] query
>   slides within a collection based on a single tag word stored in an
>   array within each document?*

Yes. Decent performance will depend on the size of your collection and, more importantly, the existence of relevant indexes.

> [Will I be able to use MongoDB, with decent performance, to] maintain
>   the database between system shutdowns and opening / closing the
>   program?

I'm assuming that you are referring to replication and failover. If so, yes, MongoDB supports this quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Let me make sure I understand you correctly regarding not using a collection for each group but instead using a collection of groups. Do you mean having a single collection where each document is a slide along with it's tags, and another collection where each document contains a group name and an array of slide id's (from the collection of slides) associated with that group?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant! From your post, when you said, "The user-created 'groups' can be individual collections, where a collection is created when a group is created..." I assumed that you meant you wanted to create a new mongodb collection for each new group. You could do this, but, it might be more troublesome down the road if you have many, many groups.